# Android ListFragment (sherlock) xml parsing from url

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-listfragment

I have problem with SherlockListFtagment and xml parser. On ListActivitiy working with AsyncTask and no have problem. What I need edit for working on ListFragment.

Code:

```
public class AndroidFragment extends SherlockListFragment{


    static final String URL = "http://...";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "novost"; // parent node
    //static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "naslov";
    static final String KEY_COST = "datum";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "text";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_LINK1 = "doc";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        Log.w("Aplikacija_view","Startovana" );
        return view;

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.w("Aplikacija_resume","Startovana" );
        new loadListView().execute();

    }

    public class loadListView extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> 
    {
        @Override protected void onPreExecute() 
        { 

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ucitavanje...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        super.onPreExecute();
        } 
        @Override protected String doInBackground(Integer... args) 
        { // updating UI from Background Thread 
        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_COST, "Datum: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                map.put(KEY_LINK1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK1));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);

            }

        return null; 
        } 
        @Override protected void onPostExecute(String args)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ucitano", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String[] from = { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST,KEY_LINK,KEY_LINK1};

            /** Ids of views in listview_layout */
            int[] to = { R.id.naslov, R.id.novost, R.id.datum,R.id.link,R.id.link1};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), menuItems, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);        

            // Setting the adapter to the listView
            setListAdapter(adapter);



                } 
                }


}
```

Application is allways is creshed. What i need to edit ?

**********Update log****************************

```
03-19 23:44:40.203: W/Aplikacija_view(30386): Startovana
03-19 23:44:40.233: W/Aplikacija_resume(30386): Startovana
03-19 23:44:40.243: W/asset(30386): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0a07000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x0103008f, style=0x00000000
03-19 23:44:40.243: W/asset(30386): deep redirect failure from 0x01030046 => 0x0a07000c, defStyleAttr=0x01010084, defStyleRes=0x0103008f, style=0x00000000
03-19 23:44:40.413: D/AndroidRuntime(30386): Shutting down VM
03-19 23:44:40.413: W/dalvikvm(30386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4200fa08)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtabwithimages/in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtabwithimages.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment AndroidFragment{42678970 #0 id=0x1020002 android} did not call through to super.onResume()
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2875)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment AndroidFragment{42678970 #0 id=0x1020002 android} did not call through to super.onResume()
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1820)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:412)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onPostResume(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:69)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5230)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
03-19 23:44:40.423: E/AndroidRuntime(30386):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: can you please post crash logs?

Comment: Yes ... I posted log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `super.onResume()` call, it seems:

```
  ...
  ...

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume(); // don't forget to call super.onResume()
      Log.w("Aplikacija_resume","Startovana" );
      new loadListView().execute();

  }  

  ...
  ...
```

Comment: This is a Logcat [03-20 00:12:10.913: I/Choreographer(3863): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.]

When is app is started, show listfragment and
them show progress and notting doing.